# Scraping text without javascript code using scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm currently setting up a bunch of spiders using scrapy. These spiders are supposed to extract **only text** (articles, forum posts, paragraphs, etc) from the target sites.

The problem is : sometimes, my target node contains a `<script>` tag and so the scraped text contains javascript code.

[Here is a link](http://www.aufeminin.com/societe/colliers-d-ambre-chez-les-bebes-attention-danger-s6952.html) to a real example of what I'm working with. In this case my target node is `//td[@id='contenuStory']`. The problem is that there's a `<script>` tag in the first child div.

I've spent a lot of time searching for a solution on the web and on SO, but I couldn't find anything. I hope I haven't missed something obvious !

### Example

HTML response (only the target node) :

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="part1">Some text</div>
    <script>var s = 'javascript I don't want';</script>
    <div id="part2">Some other text</div>
</div>
```

What I want in my item :

```
Some text
Some other text
```

What I get :

```
Some text
var s = 'javascript I don't want';
Some other text
```

### My code

Given an xpath selector I'm using the following function to extract the text :

```
def getText(hxs):
    if len(hxs) > 0:
        l = hxs.select('string(.)')
        if len(l) > 0:
            s = l[0].extract().encode('utf-8')
        else:
            s = hxs[0].extract().encode('utf-8')
        return s
    else:
        return 0
```

I've tried using XPath axes (things like `child::script`) but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try utils functions from `w3lib.html`:

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags, remove_tags_with_content

input = hxs.select('//div[@id="content"]').extract()
output = remove_tags(remove_tags_with_content(input, ('script', )))
```

Comment: @Dipnesh These functions have been moved to a new package `w3lib`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use after your xPath expression `[not (ancestor-or-self::script]`.

This will not capture scripts but you can use it to prevent other things like `[not (ancestor-or-self::script or ancestor-or-self::noscript or ancestor-or-self::style)]` this will not capture any scripts, noscripts, or any css that is not part of the text.

Example:

```
//article//p//text()[not (ancestor-or-self::script or ancestor-or-self::noscript or ancestor-or-self::style)]
```

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, Martin!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this XPath expression:

```
hxs.select('//td[@id="contenuStory"]/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script)]/text()').extract()
```

i.e, all children text nodes of descendants of `//td[@id='contenuStory']` that are not `script` nodes

To add space between the text nodes you can use something like:

```
u' '.join(
    hxs.select(
        '//td[@id="contenuStory"]/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script)]/text()').extract()
)
```

Comment: I've tried using this, the problem is when you have `<div id="content"><p>Text 1</p>Text 2</div>` you end up with `Text 2 Text 1`.

Comment: What would you want as output for `<div id="content"><p>Text 1</p>Text 2</div>`? Wouldnt you have the same for the accepted answer?

Comment: What I'm expecting is `Text 1 Text 2`. Which is what the accepted answer returns (only thing is there's no space between "1" and "Text").
I tested your answer with this example and it only returns `Text 1` for some reason ...

Comment: Ah, I see, when text nodes are direct children of your target `div`, my expression doesn't capture those. This would work though: `//div[@id="content"]/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::script)]/text()`. I've corrected my answer, also with a space between text elements.