# Scrapy: How to ignore all Javascript, JQuery, ... while scraping

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I thought I had a solution for this but of course some Websites have a different structure and it's not working there. I need to know how to get rid of all Javascript, JQuery and anything else of code that could be in the source code of a website and is not plain text.
I tried this solution here ([Scraping text without javascript code using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774340/scraping-text-without-javascript-code-using-scrapy)) on my MySpider.py and on the items.py. I don't know why it's not working with `remove_tags_with_content` but it isn't. The working files look like this at the moment:

#### MySpider.py

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
#from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags_with_content
from Scrapy_One.items import Items_Main

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'spiderName'
    allowed_domains = ['abb.de']
    start_urls = ['http://www.abb.de/']
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ('', ),
                            deny = ('/(\w|\W)*([Ii]mpressum|[Aa]bout|[Pp]rivacy|[Tt]erms|[Cc]opyright|[Hh]elp|[Hh]ilfe|[Dd]atenschutz|[Rr]echtliche(\w|\W)*[Hh]inweis|[Hh]aftungsausschlu)'),
                            unique = True),
                            callback = 'parse_stuff',
                            follow = True),
            )

    def parse_stuff(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.xpath('//html')
        items_main = []

        for site in sites:
            loader = ItemLoader(item = Items_Main(), response = response)
            loader.add_xpath('fragment', '//body//text()')
            items_main.append(loader.load_item())
            return items_main
```

#### items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join, TakeFirst
#from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags_with_content
from w3lib.html import replace_escape_chars, remove_tags

class Items_Main(Item):
    fragment = Field(
        input_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.strip(), remove_tags, replace_escape_chars),
        output_processor = Join(),
    )
```

I know this doesn't do what I want (to remove every Javascript-, JQuery-, ... code) but this is the current situation which I have to adopt.
So if you have any suggestions how to get rid of it, I'd like to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer (at least one that works for me).
I changed the following line from the **MySpider.py** `loader.add_xpath('fragment', '//body//text()')` to `loader.add_xpath('fragment', '//*[not(self::script)]/text()')`.
So the complete code of this file is now:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from Scrapy_One.items import Items_Main

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spiderName'
    allowed_domains = ['example.de']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.de/']
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = ('', ),
                            deny = ('/(\w|\W)*([Ii]mpressum|[Aa]bout|[Pp]rivacy|[Tt]erms|[Cc]opyright|[Hh]elp|[Hh]ilfe|[Dd]atenschutz|[KkCc]onta[kc]t|[Rr]echtliche(\w|\W)*[Hh]inweis|[Hh]aftungsausschlu)'),
                            unique = True),
                            callback = 'parse_stuff',
                            follow = True),
        )

    def parse_stuff(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.xpath('//body')
        items_main = []

        for site in sites:
            loader = ItemLoader(item = Items_Main(), response = response)
            loader.add_xpath('fragment', '//*[not(self::script)]/text()')
            items_main.append(loader.load_item())
            return items_main
```