# xpath string() exclude specific nodes from the rendering

Tags: python, dom, xpath, scrapy

I use scrapy and xpath to try to find a specific node in the DOM and try to render that portion as a string. This is what this portion looks like:

```html
<p><strong>Description :</strong> SCP-3976 est l'appellation collective d'une série de manifestations
 sous la forme de meurtres apparents de la célèbre autrice de romans policiers Agatha Christie<sup 
class="footnoteref"><a id="footnoteref-1" href="javascript:;" class="footnoteref" 
onclick="WIKIDOT.page.utils.scrollToReference('footnote-1')">1</a></sup>. À ce jour, toutes les instances
 de SCP-3976 ont été localisées dans les zones rurales du territoire anglais et tous les composants de 
chaque instances se trouvaient dans un rayon de 50&nbsp;mètres. De plus, toutes les instances sont 
apparues entre 22h31 et 08h36, heure locale, bien qu'aucun enregistrement ni témoin de la manifestation 
d'une instance n'existent.</p>
```

with the following code

```py
response.xpath("string(//p)").get()
```

I get that

```
Description : SCP-3976 est l'appellation collective d'une série de manifestations sous la forme de
 meurtres apparents de la célèbre autrice de romans policiers Agatha Christie1. À ce jour, toutes les 
instances de SCP-3976 ont été localisées dans les zones rurales du territoire anglais et tous les 
composants de chaque instances se trouvaient dans un rayon de 50\xa0mètres. De plus, toutes les instances 
sont apparues entre 22h31 et 08h36, heure locale, bien qu'aucun enregistrement ni témoin de la 
manifestation d'une instance n'existent.
```

Which is a pretty good result. Only, you can see that next to `Agatha Christie` is the `1` of the `<sup>`element, I'd like via xpath to prevent it from appearing. Can I do that?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a couple of `w3lib.html` functions (`remove_tags, remove_tags_with_content`), to exclude specific tags from your results.

See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774340/scraping-text-without-javascript-code-using-scrapy/19780110#19780110).

Comment: After revision, it was this solution that I needed, I saw later in a test that I had to keep some tags like span. thank!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
response.xpath('//p/text()').extract()
```

You many need to strip the output from new lines, etc. to get it into the right shape, but it will exclude the `1`.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for!