# Filter the text within <script> using xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

```
<div>
   <p>...</p>
   <script>...</script>
   <p>...</p>
   <script>...</script>
   <p>...</p> 
</div>
```

I want to extract all the texts in this **div node**,my xpath expression is like:**'string(//div)'**.
But this will also get the texts in **script label**,how do i remove them? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping text without javascript code using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774340/scraping-text-without-javascript-code-using-scrapy)

Answer (score 1):

To get text nodes from `div` excluding text from `script` nodes you can try

```
//div//text()[not(parent::script)]
```